# fxcop with Nant

Tags: nant, fxcop

How do you integrate FxCop with a NAnt script?  In my solution I have many projects with lots of DLLs.

this is my sample code:

```
<target name="runFxCop">
  <exec program="${build.dir}\tools\MicrosoftFxCop\FxCopCmd.exe" commandline="/p:${build.dir}\svn_platform.FxCop /o:${build.dir}\FxCop_Output\fxcop-results.xml" failonerror="false" />
</target>
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Analysis was not performed; at least one valid rules assembly and one valid target file must be specified.
1 total analysis engine exceptions.
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Nant is designed to run FXCop rules.

Comment: ya, but how to integrate Fxcop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may, I suggest you take a look at an [article I wrote](http://grantpalin.com/2008/01/21/net-projects-analyzing-code-with-fxcop/) on the matter some time ago. Slightly old, but still applies.

Long story short, the FxCop task in NantContrib is finicky, and requires having FxCop installed. I like to have binary tools in source control, alongside my code. To make this work, I use NAnt's `exec` task to delegate to the local (non-installed) copy of FxCop, which does the work.

Comment: @Grant Palin: thx, i that article made my day, but now i got another issue, how to give dependencies directory to fxcop,i'm using dependenciesDirectory task within fxcop but no use..may be i dn't know how to give directories..pls have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [fxcop](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc2/help/tasks/fxcop.html) task

Comment: @lan:hi, this fxcop task givin' error of fxcopcmd.exe not found.

Comment: Make sure you have FXCop installed.